# Fire an API call while navigating to another fragment

Tags: android, mvvm, retrofit2, rx-java, okhttp

I have to fire an API request at the same time I'm navigating to another fragment. Of course I get `java.lang.InterruptedException`, because the screen is closing and the call is disposed.

I use MVVM, Retrofit2, RxJava, Dagger 2.

I'm open to any solution. I'm not looking specifically for code snippets, I'd be glad if you shared your insights, your preferrable approaches to this problem with me.

My networking model is the following:

```kotlin
interface Api {

    companion object {}

    @PUT()
    @Headers()
    fun setSomething(@Body something: Something): Completable
}
```

```kotlin
class Interactor(private val api: Api) {

    fun setSomething(something: Something): Completable {
        return api.setSomething(something)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    }
}
```

```kotlin
private fun setSomething(something: Something) {
    interactor.setSomething(something)
        .subscribe({

        }, { error ->
            Timber.e(error)
        }).dispose()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) or if it's a one time thing you can also use IntentService.

Answer (score 0):

If your call is being fired while navigating to a different Fragment, maybe it doesn't belong in the Fragment's VM. Depending on the experience I imagine the call would be better suited to a VM that is scoped to the activity rather than the VM.